# Dynamically generated JSONObject null values are converted to string after saving and retrieving it from MySQL DB

Tags: java, json, spring, jdbc, gson

I am getting a JSON object from google maps and saving to MySQL DB using JdbcTemplate in a longBLOB data type. The format of JSON before saving is:-

```
{"circle_bound":["-109.99501557703037 51.202142415852514, -105.00345854406338 51.202142415852514, -105.00345854406338 47.966570619670584, -109.99501557703037 47.966570619670584, -109.99501557703037 51.202142415852514",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"count_values":["27,019"],"query_shapes":["#POLYGON#|-109.99501557703037 51.202142415852514, -105.00345854406338 51.202142415852514, -105.00345854406338 47.966570619670584, -109.99501557703037 47.966570619670584, -109.99501557703037 51.202142415852514"],"query_type":["CIRCLE"],"total_count":1,"total_points":[[{"lat":49.58436,"lng":-107.49924},180091.11,49.58436,-107.49924,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"Radius"],[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]]}
```

But while retrieving the same value from DB using jdbcTemplate the null values in json is converted to string as below:-

```
{"circle_bound":["-94.89424950944918 48.71944807447331, -93.38547461164457 48.71944807447331, -93.38547461164457 47.71414655188057, -94.89424950944918 47.71414655188057, -94.89424950944918 48.71944807447331",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"count_values":["14,872"],"query_shapes":["#POLYGON#|-94.89424950944918 48.71944807447331, -93.38547461164457 48.71944807447331, -93.38547461164457 47.71414655188057, -94.89424950944918 47.71414655188057, -94.89424950944918 48.71944807447331"],"query_type":["CIRCLE"],"total_count":1,"total_points":[[{"lat":48.216797,"lng":-94.13986},55954.83,48.216797,-94.13986,"null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","Radius"],["null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null"],["null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null"],["null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null","null"]]}
```

The table in which the JSONObject is saved is a child table named as "search_criteria_history_map". So below I am sharing the code of JdbcTemplate query:-

```
@Override
    public UserSearchCriteriaData getUserParticularSearchHistory(Map<String, String> map) throws CustomException {
        String accountUserId = map.get("accountUserId");
        String accountId = map.get("accountId");
        String searchHistoryId = map.get("searchHistoryId");

        String userSearch = "select * from search_criteria_history where user_id=? and account_id=? and id=?";
        String userSearchMap = "select * from search_criteria_history_map where criteria_id=?";
        try {
            logger.debug("Fetching user history search data from db: " + accountUserId);
            Object[] parameters = new Object[] { accountUserId, accountId, searchHistoryId };
            List<Map<String, Object>> queryForList = jdbcTemplateIRIS.queryForList(userSearch, parameters);
            
            Object[] parametersMap = new Object[] {searchHistoryId};
            List<Map<String, Object>> mapQueryForList = jdbcTemplateIRIS.queryForList(userSearchMap, parametersMap);
            
            if (queryForList.size() > 0) {
                Map<String, Object> object = queryForList.get(0);
                Map<String, Object> objectMap = null;
                if(mapQueryForList.size()>0) {
                    objectMap = mapQueryForList.get(0);
                }
                int id = (Integer) object.get("id");
                int accountID = (Integer) object.get("account_id");
                int userId = (Integer) object.get("user_id");
                HashMap<String, String[]> searchCriteria = (HashMap<String, String[]>) SerializationUtils
                        .deserialize((byte[]) object.get("search_criteria"));               
                if(searchCriteria.containsKey("Ref_SIC_Description")&&searchCriteria.get("Ref_SIC_Description")[0].trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    String[] keyMap=searchCriteria.get("Ref_keywordSICMap");
                    if(keyMap!=null && keyMap.length>0) {
                        String[] manipulateString=keyMap[0].split(" - ");
                        searchCriteria.put("Ref_SIC_Description",new String[] {manipulateString[1]});
                        
                    }
                }               
                String databseType = (String) object.get("database_type");
                Timestamp requestCompleteTime = (Timestamp) object.get("date");
                long totalCount = (Long) object.get("search_count");
                String logicalName = (String) object.get("logical_search_name");

                UserSearchCriteriaData data = new UserSearchCriteriaData(id, accountID, userId, searchCriteria,
                        databseType, requestCompleteTime, totalCount, logicalName, "","");
                UserSearchCriteriaMapData tempMapParams = new UserSearchCriteriaMapData((int)objectMap.get("map_id"),SerializationUtils
                        .deserialize((byte[])objectMap.get("search_criteria"))
                        ,(String)objectMap.get("description"),(int)objectMap.get("criteria_id") );
                data.setCriteriaMapData(tempMapParams);
                return data;
            }

        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            throw new CustomException("encountered error while fetching revised search data from db:" + userSearch,
                    AConstants.ERROR_4520, new Throwable(), true);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I need help and suggestions to get the same JSONObject back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it in java code. I used the code below to replace all "null" in JSON to null.

```
public static void cleanJson(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    for (Object key : jsonObject.keySet()) {
        Object value = jsonObject.get(key);
        if (value instanceof JSONArray) {
            JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) value;
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
                if ("null".equals(jsonArray.get(i).toString().trim())) {
                    jsonArray.set(i, null);
                } else if (jsonArray.get(i) instanceof JSONArray) {
                    JSONArray jsonInnArray = (JSONArray) jsonArray.get(i);
                    for (int j = 0; j < jsonInnArray.size(); j++) {
                        if ("null".equals(jsonInnArray.get(j).toString().trim())) {
                            jsonInnArray.set(j, null);
                        }
                    }
                } else if (jsonArray.get(i) instanceof JSONObject) {
                    cleanJson((JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i)); // Recurse for nested objects
                }
            }
        } else if ("null".equals(value.toString().trim())) {
            jsonObject.put(key, null);
        } else if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
            cleanJson((JSONObject) value);
        }
    }
}
```